# Java database concurrency

Tags: java, mysql, database, jdbc

Suppose I have a database that stores a users name and password. How can I make it so clients can concurrently read and write from the DB at the same time in java? Also, how would I avoid querying old information that has already been changed?

Is there something built in or do I have to implement my own locking system or mutex

Comment: Mysql is designed with concurrency in mind. If a data is changed, mysql will make it available to all connections. You do not need to do anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can read and write concurrently as most DB support concurrency. If clients are reading/writing different rows in the database they should always get the latest information. If they are writing or reading the same row then DB isolation levels apply. Read about it here https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/transaction-isolation-levels-dbms/

You can choose isolation you want in your application otherwise default one applies.